# add new row to a gridView devexpress control

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress-windows-ui

I am using devexpress with WinForms application. I created a `GridView` and i added a column. I want to insert a new row to this `GridView`. But when displayed there is nothing that has been shown.

Thats what i have tried:

```
public Form1()
{                
    InitializeComponent();
    loadData();
}

public void loadData()
{
    this.gridView1.AddNewRow();
    this.gridView1.SetFocusedRowCellValue(this.gridView1.Columns[0], "test");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Devexpress grid should have a data source to function correctly. If you want a simple, in-memory data source, you can use DataTable. Set it as its data source.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("mycolumn");
this.gridControl1.DataSource = dt;
```

Then it should work.